# Why slider works for two slides only?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a slider with skewed slides.
[Link to codepen](https://codepen.io/Allan11/pen/pOgMPL)

On scroll I'm adding `active` class to each slide but only two slides - 3 and 4 actually show up, 1 and 2 are not.
If you scroll you can actually see image from 2 slide show up briefly at the top of the left part.
Class is added as expected to every slide as far as I can see.
If I comment out 3 and 4 it works with 1 and 2 the same way.

I'm not sure if the problem may be somewhere in CSS styles? All the help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] which shows the actual problem and not only a link to an external resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your states backwards. When the slide is "active", it is actually moved off-screen. So all of the inactive slides are stacked in the view, allowing you to only see number 4. Unless number 4 is the active slide, in which case slide 3 shows through.

Swap your `transforms` around between default and active states.